# Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $T$ be linear operator on $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $T$ be linear operator on $V$ such that $rank(T)=rank(T^2)$.Then to prove that the null space and range space  of $T $are disjoint, i.e. zero vector is common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $v\in ker(T)\cap Im(T)$. Then $T(v)=0$ and there is $u\in V$ such that $T(u)=v$. One can see that $T(T(u))=T(v)=0$ Thus, $u\in Ker(T^2)$. Since, $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, $Ker(T^2)=Ker(T)$. Hence, $u\in Ker(T)$ and so $v=0$, as desired.

Comment: how $ker(T^2)$= ker (T)?

Comment: As you know, $Ker(T)\subseteq Ker(T^2)$. Since, $rk(T^2)=rk(T)$, one can see $Null(T^2)=Null(T)$. So $Ker(T)= Ker(T^2)$.

Comment: Sorry it is from Rank nullity theorem ?

Comment: yes, it is from Rank nullity theorem